# Identifying Television or HDMI Port info

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am trying to detect when an HDMI cable is plugged into (or removed from) a laptop or desktop running Windows 7 or above.

I called `RegisterDeviceNotification` from WinAPI and set the following:

```
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE filter;
memset(&filter, 0, sizeof(filter));
filter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
filter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
filter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR; //Detect new monitor/tv..
hNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(window, &filter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
```

It works. I get notified as follows:

```
case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
{
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE* info = (DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE*) lParam;

    switch(wParam)
    {
        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            MessageBox(NULL, info->dbcc_name, "Attached", 0);
            break;

        case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
            MessageBox(NULL, info->dbcc_name, "Detached", 0);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
break;
```

And that works fine. It prints:

`\\?\DISPLAY#SNY9C01#4&323d76f&0&UID50725632#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}`

However, I can't determine if it's the HDMI port or some other port. All I know is that its a display that is plugged in "somewhere". Any idea how I can determine which port the event came from?

Any ideas?

Comment: [Detecting Hardware Insertion and/or Removal](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal) has some good info about how to interpret the `dbcc_name` field.

Comment: @RemyLebeau; That fails for me. It shows `Generic PNP Monitor`. I had to read the Registry manually, find the device under the enum section and then parse the EDID for the device description which came up as: `Sony TV`. Now I just have to figure out how to read the HDMI port or query it on Windows.